# Stop Grid Container from rescaling when text is included

Tags: css, scale, css-grid

Im trying to build a Grid Layout for the Homescreen of my Website and it works fine so far. Six Images kinda loose on the screen, scaling works, but if i try to add text in the container below one of the Images every Image changes its size. Theyre also all doing it different, even if you only add a few letters.

https://codepen.io/FrozenYoghurt/pen/WNrjVRx

Note the behavior of the Pictures, if you add text in the `<div class="hometext01">`.
Cant figure out, why it starts rescaling immediatly and would like to know, how i can Prevent it of doing that.

HTML:

```
<div class="homescreen2">
    <div class="homeimg01 hometransition"></div>
        <div class="hometext01">test test test</div>
    <div class="homeimg02 hometransition"></div>
    <div class="homeimg03 hometransition"></div>
    <div class="homeimg04 hometransition"></div>
    <div class="homeimg05 hometransition"></div>
    <div class="homeimg06 hometransition"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.homescreen2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 110px;
    background-color: rgba(250,250,250,1.00);
    grid-template-columns:auto auto auto auto 
auto auto auto auto                     
auto auto auto auto                             
auto auto auto auto                             
auto auto auto auto                             
auto auto auto auto                             
auto auto auto auto                             
auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows:       
auto auto auto auto
auto auto auto auto
auto auto auto auto
auto auto auto auto
auto;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set your columns  to `auto`, this means the width of the column will depend on the content of the item. If you add text it will get wider. Use `1fr` instead. Also, instead of writing out 31 times `auto`, just use the `repeat` function.

In your class `.homescreen2`, use `grid-template-columns: repeat(31, 1fr);`

instead of

```
grid-template-columns:  auto auto auto auto 
                        auto auto auto auto 
                        auto auto auto auto
                        auto auto auto auto
                        auto auto auto auto
                        auto auto auto auto
                        auto auto auto auto
                        auto auto auto;
```

Comment: Thank you, did the trick. What is "fr" referring to and can i use it the same way for the rows?

Comment: `fr` is a flexible length unit, which represents a fraction of the leftover space in the grid container. In your case, it will automatically divide the entire width by 31 equal fractions. Here's a better explanation https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/

Comment: Regarding rows. There it can be tricky depending on the content of the item, because the height of an item on a website typically expands downwards without limits. Depending on your browser size or device such as mobile, the images might get very small or squished. Try to see what it looks like when you use `fr` for rows. It really comes down to your project and what you want to achieve. Usually I would stick with `auto` for rows.